# All grey image when i try to warp image perspective in Java opencv

Tags: java, opencv

I want to build an document scanner using java opencv but after transformation is performed I get an all grey outputImage

My attempt was to preprocess the image(greyscale/normalize) autodetect the corners and apply perspective transform to transform the trapezoid document into a rectangle one. The detected corners seems to be correct.

```
@Component
public class SkewHandler implements PreprocessingHandler{

    private ShapeDetector shapeDetector;

    @Autowired
    SkewHandler(ShapeDetector shapeDetector) {
        this.shapeDetector = shapeDetector;
    }

    @Override
    public Mat doPreprocessing(Mat inputImage) {
        System.out.println("skew");

        Mat greyImage = new GreyScaleHandler().doPreprocessing(inputImage);
        Mat normalizeImage = new NormalizeHandler().doPreprocessing(greyImage);
        Mat threseholdImage = new ThresholdHandler().doPreprocessing(normalizeImage);


        MatOfPoint corners = shapeDetector.getCorners(threseholdImage);
        MatOfPoint polygonCorners = shapeDetector.getApproximatePolygonCorners(corners);
        MatOfPoint frontPerspectiveCorners = shapeDetector.getFrontPerspectiveCorners(corners);
        Size frontPerspectiveSize = shapeDetector.getFrontPerspectiveSize(corners);

        Mat perspectiveTransformMatrix = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(
                        convertPoints(polygonCorners), convertPoints(frontPerspectiveCorners));

        Mat outputImage = new Mat(inputImage.size(), inputImage.type());
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputImage, outputImage, perspectiveTransformMatrix,frontPerspectiveSize);

        return outputImage;
    }

    private static MatOfPoint2f convertPoints(MatOfPoint points) {
        MatOfPoint2f points2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        points.convertTo(points2f, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        return points2f;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class ShapeDetector {

    public MatOfPoint getCorners(Mat inputImage) {
        List<MatOfPoint> corners = new ArrayList<>();
        Imgproc.findContours(inputImage,corners,new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1);

        return corners.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Imgproc::contourArea))
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public Double getCornersPerimeter(MatOfPoint2f corners) {
        return Imgproc.arcLength(corners, true);
    }

    public MatOfPoint getApproximatePolygonCorners(MatOfPoint corners) {
        MatOfPoint2f corners2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        corners.convertTo(corners2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);

        MatOfPoint2f polygonCorners2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(corners2f,polygonCorners2f, 0.015*getCornersPerimeter(corners2f),true);

        MatOfPoint polygonCorners = new MatOfPoint();
        polygonCorners2f.convertTo(polygonCorners, CvType.CV_32S);

        return polygonCorners;
    }

    public MatOfPoint getFrontPerspectiveCorners(MatOfPoint corners) {
        double maxX = corners.toList().stream()
                .mapToDouble(point -> point.x).max().getAsDouble();

        double minX = corners.toList().stream()
                .mapToDouble(point -> point.x).min().getAsDouble();

        double maxY = corners.toList().stream()
                .mapToDouble(point -> point.y).max().getAsDouble();

        double minY = corners.toList().stream().
                mapToDouble(point -> point.y).min().getAsDouble();

        double maxWidth = maxX - minX;
        double maxHeight = maxY -minY;

        return new MatOfPoint(
                new Point(0,0),
                new Point(maxWidth, 0),
                new Point(maxWidth, maxHeight),
                new Point(maxHeight, 0));
    }

    public Size getFrontPerspectiveSize(MatOfPoint corners) {
        double maxX = corners.toList().stream()
                .mapToDouble(point -> point.x).max().getAsDouble();

        double minX = corners.toList().stream()
                .mapToDouble(point -> point.x).min().getAsDouble();

        double maxY = corners.toList().stream()
                .mapToDouble(point -> point.y).max().getAsDouble();

        double minY = corners.toList().stream().
                mapToDouble(point -> point.y).min().getAsDouble();

        double maxWidth = maxX - minX;
        double maxHeight = maxY -minY;

        return new Size(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Imgproc.approxPolyDP called in getApproximatePolygonCorners() returns the corners in a different order than the order I implemented in getFrontPerspectiveCorners(). Because of that a wrong perspective matrix is created which lead to the unexpected image after Imgproc.warpPerspective call.